# Can I built an Intranet Web Application Without the need for Internet?

Tags: web-applications

I recently approached by a company that does not require internet at all but they wanted a network application to facilitate their production.

Is it possible to meet their requirement without the need of internet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,  It's called an intRAnet and it's hosted on a web server inside the company network. You won't have as many firewall issues, and access to the internal databases will be easier.  But otherwise, it's much the same - just no internet.  I'm assuming that you  are considering a browser-based application since the original question tag is "web-applications".

You could, of course, also write desktop applications with no browser necessary.  Or there is the hybrid solution, Silverlight (or similar) or desktop app with web services on the back-end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a majority of the applications I develop are for internal business needs.  They are meant to boost automation and productivity among our employees.

Plus, usually your company/organization will have a centralized LDAP repository that stores all of your employee information which makes it easier to deal with security and querying employee information.

Answer (score 1):

YES, as long as all the users (and the server) are on the local network

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.  As others have already stated, that's the whole point of an Intranet.

I'll add that a web application is a great way to go because it requires zero deployment.  Any machine with a web browser can access and use it.  Make a fix and everyone using the application uses the fixed code immediately.

Web applications can be difficult though.  There are a million frameworks for everything from the back end to the front end and everything in between.  Then you have potentially complicated server configuration to deal with.  Authorization and authentication can be a real pain. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ınstall a browser applıcatıon on a pc servıng as a server whc ıs connected on a local network workgroup. So ı need toı be able to access thıs app on another pc on d same network

Answer (score -1):

the main purpose of intranet is to use organization resource more effectively and efficiently, resources are also secured in intranet.